# Show that sets of maximum random variables is measureable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $X_1,...,X_n$ independent and identically distributed real-valued random variables on the probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$, I have to show that:
$$
  (\max\{X_1,...,X_n\} \to \infty)\in\mathbb{F}
$$
I have tried to give an answer below, however, I am unsure whether the argumentation is correct - especially regarding taking the maximum and using $\cup$ instead.

---

We know that the random variable can be written as:
$$
  X:\ \Omega \to \mathbb{R}
$$
and by definition it fullfills:
$$
  X^{-1}((-\infty,c]) = \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq c\} \in \mathbb{F}
$$
I will start by looking at the sets for a given sample of random variables with $n$ elements:
$$
  \{ \omega : \max\{X_1(\omega),...,X_n(\omega)\}\leq c\ |\ \omega \in \Omega \}
$$
So I can write
$$
 \{X_1(\omega)\leq c\ |\ \omega \in \Omega\}\land...\land\{X_n(\omega)\leq c\ |\ \omega \in \Omega\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n  \{X_i(\omega)\leq c\ |\ \omega \in \Omega\},
$$
and as $c\in\mathbb{R}$ can be arbitrary large, and that every random variable is measurable as it lives on the probability space, it must be true that 
$$
  (\max\{X_1,...,X_n\} \to \infty)\in\mathbb{F}
$$

Comment: I don’t see how the last part follows, at least not without doing a couple nontrivial extra steps.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen any hints to what these nontrivial steps are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a countable collection $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ of random variables; otherwise $$(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\to \infty)$$ is hard to make sense of.

Note that 
$$\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\}= \infty\} = \Omega \setminus \{\lim_{n\to \infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\} < \infty\}$$
and \begin{align}
\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\} < \infty\} & = \cup_{N=1}^{\infty}\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots, X_n\} < N\}. \\
& = \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \{\max\{X_1, X_2\ldots\} < N\} \\
& = \cup_{N=1}^{\infty} \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\{X_n < N\}
\end{align}